# iPhone app works fine on iPad, but not on iPhone

Tags: iphone

I've got a problem with my universal app that I just recently ported to the iPad.

While it works fine on the iPad, on the iPhone 3G it shows `Default.png` and then goes to a black screen.

It even showed the home screen after `Default.png` once, with all the icons messed up - and the home screen was still scrollable.

I've tried everything to get it working - cleaning the app and deleting then reinstalling the app but they don't seem to work.

I've rebooted my Mac and my iPhone but doing so doesn't seem to work.

Also - the app works fine in the iPhone simulator, so I'm wondering if it's my device.

Update:

I converted the app to a universal application using Xcode's 'Upgrade current target for iPad' function so there are different XIB's for each device.

I also don't have any other device to test it on - just an iPhone 3G and an iPad.

Comment: You need to post more details. This could simply be thou to the fact of a XIB file that is not configured to support smaller screens etc... what do you mean when you say that the icons are messed up? Does it work on a iPhone 4? (could signal a memory problem since iPhone 3 have less memory).

Comment: Icons messed up - tinyurl.com/262vxkq

Comment: that is really a weird error. does this work on the device?

Comment: Nope - it doesn't work on the iPhone, only on the iPad and the iPhone simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Rather easily actually - in Xcode's upgrade process, it changed an entry in the plist to not find MainWindow. It changed the entry 'Main nib file base name' to 'Main nib file base name (iPhone)'. I don't think the iPhone knew where to look for the nib because its plist entry was changed.